# I deployed my contract using Remix solidity compiler and Metamask but i don't know how to develop front end to interact with the deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

Here's link of my deployed contract: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xde3ffc9ee6fae07db8b82d53cdd4f07f645ecab5866a2fd20b4d2affde0676d8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle and testrpc are a must when developing smart contracts in solidity, also check out Jordan Leigh's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-XPBtAfcqo&t=1473s) (around 26min mark) on building a React front-end with [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to interact with a smart contract, I highly recommend his other videos too, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

for this you should chek out the following development framework, called Truffle. They have a great documentation and lots of tutorials. https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle Have fun.

PS: You will most likely have to redeploy the contract during th development, but for testing, I recommend getting the sandbox environment https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc

Have fun !

Comment: Ok, so got that testrpc will help me to deploy contract on local testnet but after deployment, how can interact with with the contract using simple web view?

Comment: That's where Truffle comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

The key ingredient is the "ABI" (Application Binary Interface) and contract address. Any JS framework that interacts with Ethereum will ask for these two details to initialize their contract libraries.

In Remix, after publishing, in the right hand panel you'll see your contract interface appear. This will include a `Copy address` link, and a `Contract Details` reveal button, that will reveal copyable fields like "interface" (which is the ABI!)

Once you have the ABI and address, you can follow the instructions on your framework of choice, whether it's Web3, Truffle, EthJS, Embark, or something else.